# Overriding css only visible on some pages

Tags: css, overriding

our site has a stylesheet.css and a custom.css - on our platform, I only have access to the custom.css.

I have some overrides in the custom.css, but they only show on some pages.

See http://www.daysjewelers.com (background, etc. controlled by custom.css)
see http://www.daysjewelers.com/category/engagement_rings_and_wedding_rings.do and the css overrides are not there.

Here are the overrides:

```
body.main {
background: #fff url(http://www.daysjewelers.com/images/en_US/global/globalgraphics/main_bg.gif) repeat;
}

.mainLayoutTable {
background: #fff;
padding: 10px;
border: 1px dashed #c0ddea;
margin-top: 15px;
}
```

and I have refreshed my browser cache, thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to define custom css styles is by adding the `!important` line to your css declaration. Your code would look like this:

```
body.main {
background: #fff url(http://www.daysjewelers.com/images/en_US/global/globalgraphics/main_bg.gif) repeat !important;
}
```

Edit: Just an FYI, I have tested this on your website using Firebug, and it did work.

Comment: thanks - that did it for me. I'm in a constant war with this platform.

Answer (score 2):

Jason, I'm noticing that in the second page that isn't working correctly - the generated source (using Firebug) reports the as having additional attributes - like bgcolor, right on the tag. I'm not really sure where that's coming from. Also if you are trying to overwrite attributes from the other template, you might consider adding !important on the declarations to ensure the attribute you want takes priority.

Comment: Yeah, something is definitely manipulating your source code (perhaps javascript?) For instance, in the Firebug generated source, there are maybe 5 or more title and meta tags, and I believe a second stylesheet.css was also generated because (while I couldn't find it in the source) there were two copies of it in the CSS panel of Firebug.

Comment: Yeah, the site is a javascript platform - so it does funky things and rewrites code, etc.